# Set Value in Text Box based on Listbox Selection XAML/PowerShell

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml

I have been looking over many similar questions on the forum but none have quite got me to where I need to be.

Background.

I am building a simple UI in Visual Studio to perform some simple tasks and then extracting the XAML code into Powershell which is responsible for the 'doing'. This choice is to keep the solution away from code based on customer request.

I am looking to use a list box which contains 3 values. There is a text box that goes with this and based on the item selected in the text box I want it to display a separate phone number.

Now I have tried multiple attacks at this from feeding in an xml file to trying a combo box. I have had it working in VS and compiled as an exe, But when I moved the XAML code to Powershell it failed due to missing missing components.

I assumed it was maybe a limitation of how I am doing it so I tried to simplify and keep it in pure XAML.

I can't seem to find the right combination of list box and text box to define it.

Simple example...

List box contains

London
Manchester
Leeds

When list box item is selected the text box will update with a separate phone number.

I am not looking for code in VS to do this it needs to be purely defined in xaml that can be lifted up and into Powershell.

**Code Start**

```
[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        Title="SAMPLECODE" Height="450" Width="800" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Window.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFAA3D3D" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Window.Background>
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="FirstSetup" Content="Initiate First Setup" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="651,383,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="132" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Height="28" BorderBrush="#FF070606" Background="#FF933838" Foreground="#FFFCFAFA"/>
        <Label Name="HostName" Content="HostName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFEFBFB" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Label Name="HostNameValue" Content="Collecting Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="148,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFF7F5F5" FontSize="14"/>
        <Label Name="UserName" Content="UserName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,83,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFEFBFB" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Label Name="UserNameValue" Content="Collecting Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="148,83,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFF7F5F5" FontSize="14"/>
        <Label Name="OSPlatform" Content="OS Platform" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="492,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFEFBFB" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Label Name="OSPlatformValue" Content="Collecting Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="596,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFF7F5F5" FontSize="14" Width="187"/>
        <Label Name="OSRelease" Content="OS Release" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="501,73,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFEFBFB" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Label Name="OSReleaseValue" Content="Collecting Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="596,73,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFF7F5F5" FontSize="14" Width="187"/>
        <Label Name="UpdateVersion" Content="Update Version" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="471,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFEFBFB" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Label Name="UpdateVersionValue" Content="Collecting Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="596,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFF7F5F5" FontSize="14" Width="187"/>
        <Label Name="LocalITDesk" Content="Local IT Desk" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,327,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFEFBFB" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" RenderTransformOrigin="2.696,-3.142"/>
        <Label Name="M365" Content="M365 Version" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="472,178,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFEFBFB" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Label Name="M365Value" Content="Collecting Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="596,178,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFF7F5F5" FontSize="14" Width="165"/>
        <ListBox Name="GlobalSDLocations" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="10,366,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="116" Background="#FFAA3D3D">
            <ListBoxItem>London</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>New York</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Singapore</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Insert More</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
        <TextBlock Name="TelNo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="49" Margin="167,207,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="165"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

"@
```

**Code End**

Appreciate any pointers

Thanks

Comment: Please post your xaml

Comment: Your ListBox need to have a binding. In VS you can make a List of (name, phonenumber) and bind it to the xaml. Pure xaml you have to define a static List in xaml

Comment: A way is to define it as xaml and fill name and phonenumber from file. Need help?

Comment: Thank-you for coming back so quickly. I have updated the Question with code extracted out of the XAML I have transfered to PowerShell (so some bits need removing and tweaking for it to work. You will see the list box is there with a placehold for the text box as I ahve tried various attempts to no avail yet on getting the string right

Comment: I think you might want a binding. That wont work in pure WPF but the rest can be done in Powershell codebehind. Here is a [deepdive about data binding in powershell](https://smsagent.blog/2017/02/03/powershell-deepdive-wpf-data-binding-and-inotifypropertychanged/)

Comment: Thanks, I had a look at that but I cant see how it directly relates to the way I am working with VS into PowerShell. Seems to be an entirely different way of doing it. Surely this cannot be that hard :)

Comment: Thanx for the link @ T-Me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My English is not that good and I hope I understood you correctly.
Your design looks really great, I just replaced the list box with a combo box, that fit better. But you are welcome to take your list box again, it works the same way.

Here is a solution that not only consists of xml, but it works that way.
If you want an XMLOnly solution you also need a list in Powershell and Databinding, but at the moment I don't know whether databinding works with Powershell.

Let me know if anything is wrong with my solution

```
[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        Title="SAMPLECODE" Height="450" Width="800" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Window.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFAA3D3D" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Window.Background>
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="FirstSetup" Content="Initiate First Setup" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="651,383,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="132" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Height="28" BorderBrush="#FF070606" Background="#FF933838" Foreground="#FFFCFAFA"/>
        <Label Name="HostName" Content="HostName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFEFBFB" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Label Name="HostNameValue" Content="Collecting Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="148,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFF7F5F5" FontSize="14"/>
        <Label Name="UserName" Content="UserName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,83,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFEFBFB" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Label Name="UserNameValue" Content="Collecting Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="148,83,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFF7F5F5" FontSize="14"/>
        <Label Name="OSPlatform" Content="OS Platform" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="492,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFEFBFB" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Label Name="OSPlatformValue" Content="Collecting Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="596,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFF7F5F5" FontSize="14" Width="187"/>
        <Label Name="OSRelease" Content="OS Release" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="501,73,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFEFBFB" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Label Name="OSReleaseValue" Content="Collecting Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="596,73,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFF7F5F5" FontSize="14" Width="187"/>
        <Label Name="UpdateVersion" Content="Update Version" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="471,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFEFBFB" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Label Name="UpdateVersionValue" Content="Collecting Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="596,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFF7F5F5" FontSize="14" Width="187"/>
        <Label Name="LocalITDesk" Content="Local IT Desk" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,327,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFEFBFB" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" RenderTransformOrigin="2.696,-3.142"/>
        <Label Name="M365" Content="M365 Version" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="472,178,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFEFBFB" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Label Name="M365Value" Content="Collecting Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="596,178,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFF7F5F5" FontSize="14" Width="165"/>
        <ComboBox Name="GlobalSDLocations" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="10,366,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="116" Background="#FFAA3D3D">
            <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">London</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>New York</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Singapore</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Insert More</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBlock Name="TelNo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="49" Margin="167,207,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="165"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@

$phoneList = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$phoneList.Add([pscustomobject]@{Country = "London"; PhoneNr= "09876"});
$phoneList.Add([pscustomobject]@{Country = "New York"; PhoneNr= "123456"});
$phoneList.Add([pscustomobject]@{Country = "Singapore"; PhoneNr= "67543345"});


$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)
$comboBox = $window.FindName("GlobalSDLocations")
$textBlock = $window.FindName("TelNo")
$textBlock.Text = ($phoneList | where Country -eq $comboBox.SelectedItem.Content).PhoneNr

$comboBox.add_SelectionChanged({$textBlock.Text = ($phoneList | where Country -eq $comboBox.SelectedItem.Content).PhoneNr})

$window.ShowDialog()
```

Best Regards

Comment: This worked out great thank-you!!!! I have incorporated that in now and its working standalone as a PowerShell application.

Comment: Just to add, I went back to a list box as a Combo Box seems to be troublesome to set a custom background colour in a clean way and it doesn't look nice against the gradient background :-)

Comment: Please see my second with binding, here you can add and delete entries programmatically to the list or combobox

Answer (score 0):

Here the same thing with Databinding thanx @T-Me

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        Title="SAMPLECODE" Height="450" Width="800" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Window.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFAA3D3D" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Window.Background>
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="FirstSetup" Content="Initiate First Setup" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="651,383,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="132" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Height="28" BorderBrush="#FF070606" Background="#FF933838" Foreground="#FFFCFAFA"/>
        <Label Name="HostName" Content="HostName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFEFBFB" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Label Name="HostNameValue" Content="Collecting Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="148,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFF7F5F5" FontSize="14"/>
        <Label Name="UserName" Content="UserName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,83,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFEFBFB" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Label Name="UserNameValue" Content="Collecting Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="148,83,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFF7F5F5" FontSize="14"/>
        <Label Name="OSPlatform" Content="OS Platform" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="492,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFEFBFB" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Label Name="OSPlatformValue" Content="Collecting Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="596,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFF7F5F5" FontSize="14" Width="187"/>
        <Label Name="OSRelease" Content="OS Release" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="501,73,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFEFBFB" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Label Name="OSReleaseValue" Content="Collecting Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="596,73,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFF7F5F5" FontSize="14" Width="187"/>
        <Label Name="UpdateVersion" Content="Update Version" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="471,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFEFBFB" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Label Name="UpdateVersionValue" Content="Collecting Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="596,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFF7F5F5" FontSize="14" Width="187"/>
        <Label Name="LocalITDesk" Content="Local IT Desk" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,327,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFEFBFB" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" RenderTransformOrigin="2.696,-3.142"/>
        <Label Name="M365" Content="M365 Version" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="472,178,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFFEFBFB" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Label Name="M365Value" Content="Collecting Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="596,178,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFF7F5F5" FontSize="14" Width="165"/>
        <ComboBox Name="GlobalSDLocations" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="10,366,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="116" Background="#FFAA3D3D">
            
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBlock Name="TelNo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="49" Margin="167,207,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="165"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@

$phoneList = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$phoneList.Add([pscustomobject]@{Country = "London"; PhoneNr= "09876"});
$phoneList.Add([pscustomobject]@{Country = "New York"; PhoneNr= "123456"});
$phoneList.Add([pscustomobject]@{Country = "Singapore"; PhoneNr= "67543345"});
$phoneList.Add([pscustomobject]@{Country = "Germany"; PhoneNr= "4949494949"});



$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)
$comboBox = $window.FindName("GlobalSDLocations")


$DataContext = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[Object]

$DataContext.Add($phoneList.Country)
$comboBox.DataContext = $DataContext


# Create and set a binding on the textbox object
$Binding = New-Object System.Windows.Data.Binding 
$Binding.Path = "[0]"
$Binding.Mode = [System.Windows.Data.BindingMode]::OneWay
[void][System.Windows.Data.BindingOperations]::SetBinding($comboBox,[System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox]::ItemsSourceProperty,$Binding)


$textBlock = $window.FindName("TelNo")
$textBlock.Text = ($phoneList | where Country -eq $comboBox.SelectedItem).PhoneNr

$comboBox.add_SelectionChanged({$textBlock.Text = ($phoneList | where Country -eq $comboBox.SelectedItem).PhoneNr}) 

$comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0
$window.ShowDialog()
```

Best Regards